# Múltiples Valores en una Variable en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde resumo los siguientes datos

```
Valor   Periodo
1   2023-06
2   2022-06
3   2023-06
3   2022-06
4   2023-06
5   2022-06
5   2023-06
5   2022-06
6   2023-06
8   2021-06
8   2021-06
```

Al realizar varios Inner Join con diferentes tablas, requiero de una variable como por Ejemplo la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Periodo Char(7) = '2021-06','2022-06','2023-06'
```

Pero me saca error ya que solo admite un valor.

Necesito incluir esta variable en un Where.
Por ejemplo que quede:

*From ...
inner join...
Where SQ2 in (@periodo,@date)*

Teniendo en cuenta que @periodo tiene incluido ('2021-06','2022-06','2023-06')

Comment: ¿Con qué motor de base de datos estás trabajando? ¿En dónde vas a utilizar esos datos? No olvides proveer contexto. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola estoy usando SQL Server Management studio 19

Comment: Entonces tu motor de base de datos es SQL Server. Pulsa en [edit] para colocarlo en las etiquetas, y no olvides describir el contexto de tu pregunta.

Comment: No confundas la herramienta (SSMS) con el motor de base de datos (SQL Server).

Comment: ¿Por qué no hacer una subconsulta, si querés usar los valores seleccionados en un `where`?

Answer (score 3):

Las variables en SQL Server, por lo general solo pueden tener un valor escalar. Para tener múltiples valores puede usar una variable tipo tabla.

```
DECLARE @Periodos TABLE( periodo Char(7)); 

INSERT INTO @Periodos
VALUES('2021-06'), ('2022-06'), ('2023-06');
```

Esta variable la puedes utilizar como si fuera otra tabla y así poder usar los múltiples valores que contiene.

Para usar los valores en un WHERE, puedes usar IN o EXISTS.

```
SELECT *
FROM AlgunaTabla
WHERE AlgunValor IN ( SELECT periodo FROM @Periodos);
```

Otras alternativas pueden ser el uso de XML,JSON o cadenas con valores concatenados. Sin embargo, estas opciones requieren de más código y no tienen el mismo rendimiento.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero necesito incluir esa variable en un Where.
Por ejemplo que quede:
*Where SQ2 in (@periodo,@date)*

Teniendo en cuenta que @periodo tiene incluido ('2021-06','2022-06','2023-06')

Comment: @CarlosF ¡Ese es el contexto que debés explicar en tu pregunta!

Comment: @CarlosF Revisa la respuesta otra vez. La edité para incluir lo que preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible almacenar más de un valor en una variable escalar.

Pero puedes pasar la lista en formato JSON

```
declare @Periodo nvarchar(max) = '["2021-06","2022-06","2023-06"]';
```

Luego para cualquier consulta haces:

```
SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@Periodo)
```

```
2021-06
2022-06
2023-06
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero me saca el siguiente error
*Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.*

Comment: @CarlosF Tu base de datos no tiene el lvl suficiente, prueba cambiarlo a 130 `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130`

Answer (score 0):

Si debes almacenar los valores en una variable, probablemente la función que podrías usar es [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) para volver a convertir dichos valores en filas de tabla, del tipo:

```
declare @periodo varchar(8000) = '2021-06,2022-06,2023-06'
select *
from UnaTabla inner join OtraTabla
where SQ2 in (select value from string_split(@periodo, ','))
```

En todo caso, si tu `@@version` de SQL Server es inferior a la 2016, puedes crear una función similar:

```
CREATE Function Split (@list varchar(8000), @del varchar(1))
returns @ret table (value varchar(8000)) as
begin
    select @del = case len(@del) when 0 then ' ' else @del end, @list += @del
    declare @bit varchar(8000), @pos smallint = charindex(@del, @list)
    while @pos > 0
    begin
        select @bit  = nullIf(ltrim(rtrim(left(@list, @pos - 1))),'')
            ,  @list = stuff(@list, 1, @pos, '')
            ,  @pos  = charindex(@del, @list)
        insert into @ret values (@bit)
    end
    return
end
```

quedando el `where` así:

```
where SQ2 in (select value from dbo.Split(@periodo, ','))
```

Comment: Hola, no es tanto como retornarlo en una tabla, si no el listado que esta de periodos es volverlo en un consecutivo en la variable separado por '' y , ya que al ser texto en el Where solo se podra buscar por comillas separado por comas